# alid initializer type list found for map : expected a map with the same keys and values or a valid SObject list

Tags: soql, map, collection

The code below causes the error mentioned in the title. Not sure what this means or how to fix it.

```
        Map <ID,ID> mapID = new Map<ID,ID>([SELECT ContactId, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityContactRole]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't initialize a `Map<Id, Id>` from a SOQL query result. Passing a SOQL query (or list of sObjects) to the `Map` constructor is valid for producing a `Map<Id, sObject>`.

It's not clear from your question which Id you want to map to which other Id, but in any case, you'll need to iterate over the query results to build your `Map`.

Comment: He could group the query by needed Id field and rename it like this `[SELECT ContactId Id, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityContactRole GROUP BY ContactId]` this then can be used in the `Map<Id, AggregatedResult>` constructor. But this approach has its own limitation.

Comment: Thx @DavidReed.